# Gnu CALC: vector/matrix concatenation in horizontal axis?

Tags: calc

I'm just few days in learning about GNU-CALC. This is very awesome package.

Suppose I have 2 matrices (or column vector) with shape of 3x1:

```
2:  [ [ a1 ]
      [ a2 ]
      [ a3 ] ]
1:  [ [ b1 ]
      [ b2 ]
      [ b3 ] ]
    .
```

The `calc-concat` (bind to <kbd>|</kbd>): will concatenates (vertically) to following 6x1 matrix:

```
1:  [ [ a1 ]
      [ a2 ]
      [ a3 ]
      [ b1 ]
      [ b2 ]
      [ b3 ] ]
```

**What I want to know:** How to concatenate horizontally such that it results following 3x2 matrix?

```
1:  [ [ a1, b1 ]
      [ a2, b2 ]
      [ a3, b3 ] ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transpose the matrix before concatening them:

```
'[a1;a2;a3] RET
1:  [ [ a1 ]
      [ a2 ]
      [ a3 ] ]
'[b1;b2;b3] RET
2:  [ [ b1 ]
      [ b2 ]
      [ b3 ] ]

vt
TAB
vt
TAB
|
vt
1:  [ [ a1, b1 ]
      [ a2, b2 ]
      [ a3, b3 ] ]
```

If you have many such operation, you can make a keyboard macro.

```
;; Keyboard Macro Editor.  Press C-c C-c to finish; press C-x k RET to cancel.
;; Original keys: v t TAB v t TAB |

Command: last-kbd-macro
Key: none

Macro:

v t         ;; calc-transpose
TAB         ;; calc-roll-down
v t         ;; calc-transpose
TAB         ;; calc-roll-down
|           ;; calc-concat
```

Comment: I think there is a TAB missing bit just before the concatenation, right?

Comment: You are right. I'm not very comfortable with SE's online editor.

Comment: Code blocks and cut-n-paste are your friends :-)